# Links that blink on click with Framer Motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

In my Next.js app, I'd like to implement links as buttons that "blink" once when clicked, similar to how Mac OS menu items behave.

Specifically, the link-button has to defer navigating to its destination until the blink animation completes. This seems to be not possible with Framer Motion's [gesture system](https://www.framer.com/docs/gestures/). It should be possible with [AnimatePresence](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/), but I haven't been able to make it work.

#### Example

[image: Example of "blink on click" animation in Mac OS]

#### What I Tried

I have tried the code below, which produces no animation at all:

###### BlinkButton.js

```
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function BlinkButton(props) {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <motion.button
        key={props.id}
        className="..."
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.1 }}
      >
        {props.children}
      </motion.button>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}
```

##### SomeOtherComponent.js

```
<Link href={href}>
  <BlinkButton id={label}>
    {icon}
    <p>{label}</p>
  </BlinkButton>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping your AnimatePresence around your motion.div you need to wrap it around BlinkButton.

```
<Link href={href}>
<AnimatePresence>
  <BlinkButton id={label}>
    {icon}
    <p>{label}</p>
  </BlinkButton>
</AnimatePresence>
</Link>
```